# How to visually disable ("hide") Smooth Shading in Edit Mode only?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, edit-mode, shaders

In Blender 2.8, is it possible to visually disable Smooth Shading ONLY in Edit Mode? I want the surface of my model to soften in Object Mode or render preview, but at the same time, when I enter Edit Mode, the surface stays "low poly".

As an example, there is an option within the Subdivision Surface modifier that allows you to visually disable the modifier within Edit Mode. Is there something similar for Smooth Shading?

Thank you.